# Вопрос, скорее, из истории

Tags: этимология, ономастика

Может быть, вопрос больше касается истории, нежели филологии, но все же.
Известно, что первыми русскими князьями были братья-варяги Рюрик, Трувор и Синеус. Но почему у первых двух братьев имена явно варяжские, а вот Синеус - имя русское (от "синий ус")? Или же оно просто созвучно русским словам?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, конечно не русское. Синеус - такое же варяжское имя, как и два других.

*Синеус (м.) – имя собств., др.-русск. Синеусъ (Пов. врем. лет под 862 г.). Объясняют из др.-сканд. Signiutr, Signjótr, буквально "наслаждающийся победой" (Томсен, Urspr. 74). Могло сблизиться с си́ний и усъ*.
© Фасмер

Answer (score 0):

Тут надо заметить, что вполне возможно, Синеус - это вовсе не имя, а следствие неправильного перевода Повести Временных Лет. Некоторые историки считают, что братьев Рюрика Синеуса и Трувора в действительности не существовали. Например, Борис Рыбаков полагает, что имя «Синеус» представляет собой искаженное «свой род» (швед. sine hus), а «Трувор» — «верная дружина» (швед. thru varing). И пришел Рюрик княжить не со своими двумя братьями, а со своим родом и верной дружиной. А российский академик Дмитрий Лихачёв и вовсе предположил, что Рюрик, Синеус и Трувор - «мистические пращуры» Новгорода, такие как Кий, Щек и Хорив для Киева. В последнем случае возможны и славянские корни имени.

Comment: Дисхрония какая-то.
Какой "шведский" в девятом веке?

Comment: Так-то оно так, я и сам лингвистическим изысканиям Рыбакова не особо доверяю, но смысла в появлении братьев, которые пришли сели и умерли, как-то уж совсем нету. Зачем их тогда вообще включать в летопись? Это и рождает различные предположения.

Comment: Это другой вопрос, не языковой. Конечно же, история про призвание варягов  Бояном выдумана, Нестором писана и Карамзиным освящена. Пришли, **завоевали** и сели княжить - вот это гораздо вернее. Но к этимологии имени это никак не относится.

Comment: @behemothus, не всё так просто. Завоевал - это доблестный поступок, зачем его скрывать? Завоевание Киева Олегом ведь не скрывалось, пусть и окрашено это событие довольно-таки тенденциозно. Да и как-то быстро для завоевателей они ассимилировались, уже внук Рюрика имел славянское имя. Приглашение князя вполне в духе Новгорода. Но это, действительно, не языковой вопрос.

Что касается языка, то возможные версии помимо Фасмера, я описал ещё в ответе.